# Como tirar as bordas de um JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Eu gostaria de retirar as bordas de um `JFrame`. Eu usei `setUndecorated(true)`, porém ele retira completamente e eu gostaria de deixar apenas a barra de título do `JFrame`.

Comment: **+1**. Se tem algo pronto que faça exatamente isso, eu nunca ouvi/vi falar. Das vezes que precisei criar algo semelhante, usei `setUndecorated(true)` e "criei" a barra de título com um `JPanel`. Usei um `JButton` para cada botão de ação, fazer aqueles eventos de minimizar/fechar a janela não é difícil, tem vários exemplos na internet - *e claro, a possibilidade de customizar a seu gosto os ícones, fontes, cores, etc*.

Comment: Já tentou usar o setBorder()? colocar tudo 0?

Answer (score 2):

As bordas da janela são fornecidas pelo sistema operacional (desde que a janela esteja marcada como decorada). A decoração da janela inclui a barra de título, então você não pode ter uma coisa sem ter a outra.

Existe uma forma de fazer: você pode definir sua janela como não-decorada e implementar uma barra de título na mão. O problema é que você teria que fazer os botões de maximizar, minimizar e fechar você mesmo, se preocupando com o posicionamento correto deles (no Mac OS e no Ubuntu é diferente do Window). Sem contar que teria que fazer na mão com que essa barra responda ao arrastar e soltar. Ou seja, não vale a pena (mas o pessoal do Chrome fez!)